# Android always SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, nexus-4, socket-timeout-exception, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Sometimes I get into a state in which I always get SocketTimeoutException. Application restart does not work. Only phone restart works. What can be the cause and fix?

I am running the app on an Android 4.3 Nexus 4 btw.

Comment: It's hard to help without code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be about the computer on which the server is running. Turning Wifi on and off on the server machine solved the issue.